# Cancelling a task running in a different namespace

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I was just wondering what is the best way to do this. At the moment I have declared the `CancellationTokenSource` in the GUI namespace so I can invoke it when a button is pressed.

```
namespace Namespace1
{
    public class Number1
    { 
    CancellationTokenSource cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ....
```

and I have then written a constructor that accepts a `CancellationTokenSource` parameter and assigns it to a locally declared field which I then use in my methods.

```
namespace Namespace2
{
    public class Number2
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancelToken;

        public testing(CancellationTokenSource cancelToken)
        {
            this.cancelToken = cancelToken;
        }
        ... default constructor and method(s) follow.
```

Should I be writing this in a different way or is this ok?

Comment: Does your current approach work as you expect (I know the code above won't)?

Comment: Namespaces are a compile time concept - they do not exist at runtime. I'm still not sure, having read your narrative and seen your examples what specific problem you're having.

Comment: If you want to cancel something, you shouldn't give it `CancellationTokenSource`, just a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: In addition, in general *one* piece of code should create a `CancellationTokenSource` object - everything else after that should just be accepting a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: Yes it seems to works correctly, but i havent seen an example similar to it which got me thinking i was doing something which was generally frowned upon.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I havent had alot of experience with CancellationTokens, but i will try and see if i can get it to accept a CancellationToken instead of the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespaces help you organize your code.

You will need to expose your `CancellationTokenSource` variable somehow.  You can't just have a variable floating around outside the class definition.

I recommend you use a *property*.  You can expose the `CancellationTokenSource` as a public property from an instance of the class, for example, so that other classes, even if they are in other namespaces, have access to it.  Avoid using public variables.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    namespace SomeOtherSpace
    {
        public class TokenWrapper
        {
            public CancellationToken CancelToken { get; set; }
        }
    }

    namespace YetAnotherSpace
    {
        public class AnotherClass
        {
            private readonly CancellationToken _Token;
            public AnotherClass(CancellationToken token)
            {
                _Token = token;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeOtherSpace.TokenWrapper wrapper = new SomeOtherSpace.TokenWrapper();
            wrapper.CancelToken = new CancellationToken();
            YetAnotherSpace.AnotherClass anotherClass = new YetAnotherSpace.AnotherClass(wrapper.CancelToken);
        }
    }
}
```

**edit**

In response to your comment, a better idea would be to have your could create one `CancellationTokenSource`, and then pass the `CancellationToken` around to classes that need to subscribe to it.  It suits almost every scenario I can think of well.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource sourceToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { MyTask(sourceToken.Token); });
}

static void MyTask(CancellationToken token)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: "You can't just have a variable floating around outside the class definition." i though i had it declared inside the class and that it was private by default? Is it possible to have it as a static property so i wouldnt have to pass an instance around? Thanks for your help, much appreciated

Comment: @HansRudel: Updated my answer regarding your comment.

Comment: Duly noted, ill incorporate that into my project. Thanks very much for your help!